# Assembly help for INT 13h on Disk Information

Tags: assembly, x86, bios

I am using DOSBox and nasm, trying to use int 13 in order to get hard disk information such as serial code etc.
Int 13 needs:

```
    AH=25h
    DL=(80h,81h) and 
    ES:BX-> 512 byte buffer for reply packet.
```

i dont understand the requirements of the final line at all. any help?

An example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The registers `es` and `bx` supply the far address of the buffer to receive the data, the buffer is 512 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

As you know `es` and `bx` are 16 bits registers.

`es` is the segment, while `bx` is the offset.

If you concatenate them `[es:bx]` you get the full 32 bit address (AKA pointer) to the "buffer", which the data will be copied to from the disk device.

Here is a snippet should work for you:

```
xor ax,ax
mov ah,25h
mov dl,80; 81h is for write probably
mov bx,0h
mov es,0800h
int 13
```